# Android 4.0.3 unable to use large pictures to repeat background?

Tags: android, background

I have the following testbackground.xml file:

```
<bitmap
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:src="@drawable/popup_light_background_img_small"
android:tileMode="repeat"
android:dither="true" 
/>
```

Which when set as a background creates a repeating background image.

@drawable/popup_light_background_img_small is a 64x64 image, but If I replace it with an image which is 100x100 pixel then the background will not repeat. It just show the image once, and then repeat the last pixel in the image, instead of the entire image. Anyone who have idea about why that is?